# Xcode 7.3 doesn't show error(warning) about unimplemented delegate method in protocol declaration

Tags: ios, delegates, protocols, xcode7.3

I have updated Xcode 7.3. I observe that Xcode doesn't shown the error(warning) to implement the delegate method which are marked as **@required** in custom protocol declaration.

Project is building successfully without implement Required delegate method. However it gives "Unrecognised selector sent to instance" error when I tried to call delegate method at runtime, the error is obvious, but I am curious about why Xcode stops showing it at compile time.

In older version(e.g Xcode 6.4) It gives. If anyone have any idea then please share it.
Thanks in advance.

Here is my protocol declaration, 
CustomViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol MyCustomProtocol <NSObject>

- exampleDelegateMethod: (NSString*) test;

@end

@interface CustomViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id  <MyCustomProtocol> delegate;

@end
```

---

And in another class I am listening to delegate method which I declared,

**in .h file**,

```
#import "CustomViewController.h"
@interface AnotherViewController : UIViewController <MyCustomProtocol>
```

**in .m file**,

```
        ((CustomViewController*)segue.destinationViewController).delegate = self;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) Can you show us  [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) ?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Hello @Abhi and "@Ulrich" can you please check now.

Answer (score 0):

I got the fault, instead of listening to delegate like,

```
((CustomViewController*)segue.destinationViewController).delegate = self;
```

Changed it to,

```
CustomViewController* subscriptionViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
CustomViewController.delegate = self;
```

This solved my problem.
Thanks for everyones effort who have spent time on this.